# Distributed version control for configuration settings

Tags: git, hadoop, dvcs

I am running several Hadoop clusters and one best practice that became very handy was to use distributed version control systems to have a revision control for configuration files.

Example: for Hadoop, I create a GIT repository on in the etc directories. This was very helpful, as I was able to revert to earlier configuration settings. The only drawback is that if more people configure the server and one admin does not commit regularly after a change, the idea is gone.

Is there any better recommendation on how to do some revision control on configuration files?

Stefan

Comment: You should use a proper configuration management solution, not just **git** alone. Among possible solutions: [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com), [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/), [SaltStack](http://www.saltstack.com/).

Comment: Also please stop using [valedictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction) and signatures, they just add noise. We already know who asked the question and that you're grateful for any answers blah blah blah. See [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/135744) from Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allowing users to edit the working directory directly you could deny write acces to all users except a single super-user. The regular users should only be able to edit their local copy of the configuration files, and when they are ready to write them to the server they can use `git branch -f branch_name new_commit`, and then push to a bare repository that is not connected to any working directory.

If all servers are supposed to have the same settings you can configure a post-receive hook to update all servers using the superuser login whenever your "production" (or whatever you want to call it) branch is updated. (You must allow force update for this branch if you want rollbacks to work.)

If you sometimes need distinct settings for some servers you can have a branch for each server, e.g., production/server-1 production/server-2, etc. Modify the update script to only update the server corresponding to the updated branch.

Of course you will have to configure security on your repository.

You can use a service like [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/) which can give you branch-by-branch permission configuration.

See the following links for more on [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) or [Gitolite](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite).